# How to create child classes like mysqli class in php

Tags: php, class

I am building a little website, and i currently have a problem dealing with classes.
I want to create a class named `message_manager` which has a child named `send` (like mysqli class that has query has a child).

I need this because I want to have variables in `send` class.
can someone help me with it.

```
    class message_manager{
       var $sender; 
       var $connection;

       function __construct($connection, $sender){
         $this -> sender = sender; $this -> connection = $connection;
       }
    }

    class send extends message_manager{
      var $message_id;

      private function _send($receiver, $message){

        //function that sends the message and generate $id
        $this -> message_id = $id;
     }

     function __construct($receiver, $message){
       return $this -> _send($receiver, $message)
     }
   }
```

//Sending a message

```
$conn = new mysqli(....);
$messenger = new message_manager($conn, $user1);
$a = $messenger -> send($user2, $message);
$id = $a -> message_id;
```

I have tried the above code but it does not work.
Any help or work-around is welcome.

Comment: You're instantiating a `message_manager` class, but that doesn't have a `send()` method.... but what is the relationship between your `message_manager` and `send` classes, because it doesn't seem to be one of inheritance

Comment: The `mysqli` class doesn't have a `query` class, it has a `query` *method*. The *method* returns a result *object* (of the `mysql_result` class). You're extending (inheriting), they don't. You probably should read up on those concepts first ;o/

Comment: Thanks for all. By what I understand now, `send` should be a method of `message_manager` that return an other class.
Is it rigth